# How would I save a JS variable so it can be used on another HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have two HTML pages. On the first page I add values to an array.

```
thisArray.push("new value");
```

On the second HTML page I want to print this array to a textArea

```
for(i=0; i<thisArray.length;i++){

        var thisName = thisArray[i];
        document.getElementById('listOfNames').innerHTML +=  thisName + '\n';    

    }
```

But when I change the page obviously the browser wont know about the other variable. What's the best way to do this ?

I thought of saving the value locally?
Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.localStorage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Example:

```
 window.localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(arrayData)
```

And then parse JSON when read the data on another page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist the value,

```
localStorage.setItem('itemName', itemValue);
```

then to fetch the item just use

```
localStorage.getItem('itemName');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `localStorage.setItem(key,value)`

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library which allows you to set and read javascript cookies easily.

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Example:

Set cookie on first page:

```
Cookies.set('thisArray', JSON.stringify(thisArray));
```

Read cookie on second page:

```
var thisArray = Cookies.getJSON('thisArray');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least, two options to do what you want, one is pass that variable on the url query like:

```
www.mypage.com?my_javascript_var=12345
```

Another option is using `localstorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('itemName', varToBeSaved);
```

then, to get the variable back on any page

```
var mySavedVar = localStorage.getItem('itemName');
```